# Rabbi Yaakov of Krozh's book

Tags: sources-mekorot, jewish-books, rabbis

Rabbi Yitzchak Hertzog zt"l in his short essay (in Hebrew) "למידותיו של חזקיהו מלך יהודה" (On the Traits of Chizkiyahu King of Yehudah), published in the Sinai Jubilee Volume, pp. 27-28 wrote:

> "כדאי להזכיר מה שקראתי בימי בחרותי בספר קטן שחיבר צדיק אחד, ושמו רבי יעקב מקראז ז"ל, מבית מדרשו של הגאון מווילנא. הוא אומר: היות ובימיו (בימי ריב"ז) נחלקו עליו כמה תלמידי חכמים שלא צדק בהתנגדותו המוחלטת למרד כנגד רומי, והיו מצטטים והולכים לו את הדוגמא המזהירה של חזקיה מלך יהודה שמרד במלך אשור, ולסוף עשה לו הקב"ה נס, ואמר ברגעיו האחרונים לפני פטירתו (ברכות כח, ב): "הכינו כסא לחזקיהו מלך יהודה", וכוונתו היתה כי חזקיהו יוצא לקבל פני, הא אין מחלוקת בינינו "הוא צדק בזמנו ואני צדקתי בזמני"."

**Edit:**

Based on a search in Otzar Hachochmah and via Google, it seems that Rabbi Yaakov of Krozh's last name was Elyon/Elion/Ilion (עליון/עליאן) (all spellings are used at times). According to R' Shmuel Noach Gottleib in his book [Ohalei Shem, p. 35](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=36602&st=&pgnum=79) he was known as רבי יענקעלע קראזער, was a grandson of Rabbi Nechemiah student of the Vilna Gaon, and was himself a student of Rabbi Chaim of Volozhin. He was born in [Krozh](https://kehilalinks.jewishgen.org/kraziai/krozh_a_shtetl_in_lithuania.htm) and eventually became the אב"ד of Zhezmir. Near the end of his life he made aliyah and settled in Yerushalayim, until his death in 1877 ([link](https://mountofolives.co.il/he/deceased_card/%D7%9E%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%9C%D7%90-%D7%99%D7%93%D7%95%D7%A2-miriam-13/) to his grave profile). One of his sons was [Rabbi Yekutiel Leib Elyon](https://isheiisrael.wordpress.com/2020/12/25/%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%99-%D7%99%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%AA%D7%99%D7%90%D7%9C-%D7%A2%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%95%D7%9F/), who authored the books Gilayon Maharil (גליון מהרי"ל) and Chibat Hakodesh (חבת הקדש).

I was unable to find references to books he wrote. Does anyone know which book Rabbi Hertzog was referring to?

Comment: Here is his grave: https://mountofolives.co.il/he/deceased_card/%D7%99%D7%A2%D7%A7%D7%91-%D7%9C%D7%90-%D7%99%D7%93%D7%95%D7%A2-yaakov-18/#gsc.tab=0 and he's mentioned here: https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46565&st=&pgnum=184 but I can't track down any books

Comment: I wonder if maybe Rabbi Herzog made a small mistake and was actually quoting from one of the books of the son. Have you looked thru them to see if this idea is mentioned there?

Comment: @JoelK I also thought about that, and I checked both, but couldn't find anything. I also considered he was thinking about the grandfather, but haven't yet found any books by him either.